# Mysql Stored Procedure error #1064

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, pivot-table

```
              SET @sql = NULL;

              SELECT 
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
                              CONCAT('sum(case when week = ',week,
                                     'then totaltime else 00 end) AS `',
                                         week, '`')
                             )INTO @sql
                FROM   mytable;

                 SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT TRIM(UPPER(mytable.empcode))AS CODE, 
                 TRIM(UPPER(mytable.empname)) EMPNAME,
                 ', @sql, ' 
                 from  mytable
                 group by empcode
                 order by empname ');
           PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
           EXECUTE stmt;
           DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
           END
```

I am using pivot table here, want to make sum of totaltime according to week field which is dynamically generated by query, but I got an error :

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'from mytable group by empcode or' at line 6"

Comment: where is from timesheetreport1 ? code incomplete?

Comment: oops sorry it was my mistake its mytable

Comment: add relevant portions in question/edit

Comment: it runs properly when my time diff between fromdt and todt is less but gives me an error when i increase it

Comment: Issue has been solved i have to add SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;